# What was the use of the doll?

Tags: typewriter

In the series *Typewriter* (2019), it was clearly very important to Fakeer to have the doll that resembled him. That's why he demanded a piece of wood in prison and spent so much time whittling by hand (and, one assumes, a bit of magic). It was clearly useful in some sense to the attempt to revive him, thus why "Amit Roy" needed it. And it obviously had some sort of supernatural power.

However, the doll didn't contain Fakeer's soul; the typewriter did. As we saw from the first time he tried to return to his body, the doll wasn't in the room, and the discussion around souls returning to their bodies in the book written by the ghost, didn't make any mention of the need for a doll. Even if somehow the doll *had* contained his soul originally, by the present day his soul was within the typewriter, and the mere fact that the typewriter could hold his soul suggests that there'd be no need for a doll that resembled him to contain it. In any case he certainly didn't seem to have informed Madhav of the need for the doll, despite intending to return three days later. It wasn't what linked him to Jenny, either: her getting blood on the typewriter did that. So why was the doll so important?

Comment: "As we saw from the first time he tried to return to his body, the doll wasn't in the room" - this is not quite clear. One of the people present gives the doll to young Jenny shortly before Fakeer awakens. It is conceivable that his spirit transfers from the doll to the body before the doll is given to Jenny, and it just took a couple of moments before Fakeer could actually revive the body. With that said, the doll still seemed to be meaningful to Fakeer even after that.

Comment: Also, as gets apparent in 1x05, *something* was living inside the doll, even if it's not quite clear what it was.